# How do I dynamically call 2 different cmdlets with the same parameters? (Not dynamic parameters.)

Tags: powershell

I have code similar to

```
if ($condition) {
  do-it1 -param1 "cookies" -param2 "eat"
  do-it1 -param1 "bananas" -param2 "peal"
  do-it1 -param1 "apples" -param2 "core"
  do-it1 -param1 "parachuting" -param2 "dont"
} else {
  do-it2 -param1 "cookies" -param2 "eat"
  do-it2 -param1 "bananas" -param2 "peal"
  do-it2 -param1 "apples" -param2 "core"
  do-it2 -param1 "parachuting" -param2 "dont"
}
```

what I want to do is something like

```
if ($condition) {
  $doWhat = do-it1
} else {
  $doWhat = do-it2
}

$doWhat -param1 "cookies" -param2 "eat"
$doWhat -param1 "bananas" -param2 "peal"
$doWhat -param1 "apples" -param2 "core"
$doWhat -param1 "parachuting" -param2 "dont"
```

In C$ I would just use a delegate or something more OO.

```
Action<string,string> doWhat = condition? doIt1:doIt2;
doWhat("cookies","eat");
doWhat("bananas","peal");
doWhat("apples","core");
doWhat("parachuting","dont");
```

In my real code I am not using constants as the parameters to `doWhat`.

How can I change what cmdlet my script is calling without duplicating code with a bunch of similar if branches?

Thanks in advace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The first three examples here deal with how I would personally approach refactoring code like the sample you've shown, the answer to your **specific** question is covered at the very bottom :)*

PowerShell supports splatting - that is, multiple named parameter arguments can be passed as a single dictionary:

```bsh
$paramArgs = @{
 "param1" = "cookies"
 "param2" = "eat"
}

if ($condition) {
  do-it1 @paramArgs
}
else {
  do-it2 @paramArgs
}
```

So create an array of dictionaries, one per invocation, and we can reduce the code to:

```
$paramArgTables = @(
  @{ param1="cookies"; param2="eat"}
  @{ param1="bananas"; param2="peal" }
  @{ param1="apples"; param2="core" }
  @{ param1="parachuting"; param2="dont" }
)

if ($condition) {
  $paramArgTables |ForEach-Object {
    do-it1 @_
  }
}
else {
  $paramArgTables |ForEach-Object {
    do-it2 @_
  }
}
```

You can also take it a step further by invoking the target command by name using the `&` call operator (which also supports splatting):

```
$paramArgTables = @(
  @{ param1="cookies"; param2="eat"}
  @{ param1="bananas"; param2="peal" }
  @{ param1="apples"; param2="core" }
  @{ param1="parachuting"; param2="dont" }
)

$cmdName = if($condition){
  'do-it1'
}
else{
  'do-it2'
}

$paramArgTables |ForEach-Object {
  & $cmdName @_
}
```

Which means you can also do exactly what you want:

```
$cmdName = if($condition){
  'do-it1'
}
else{
  'do-it2'
}

& $cmdName -param1 "cookies" -param2 "eat"
& $cmdName -param1 "bananas" -param2 "peal"
& $cmdName -param1 "apples" -param2 "core"
& $cmdName -param1 "parachuting" -param2 "dont"
```

I just really prefer splatting :)

Comment: I dig splatting too. Unfortunately the called cmdlet uses cmdlet binding and doesn't seem to work with splatting.

Comment: @DrFloyd5 FWIW There's zero difference from the point of the cmdlet itself - parameter binding is handled by a separate component in the API, so the arguments received by `Do-It1` are exactly the same whether you do `Do-It1 -param1 value` or `$p=@{param1='value'}; Do-It1 @p`

Comment: the & operator is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!